# Question one proposition about the elimination theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have some questions about **Proposition 7.18** on the following [PDF](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014-c7.pdf).

> **Proposition 7.18** The projection map $\pi : \mathbb{P}^{n} \times \mathbb{P}^{m} \to \mathbb{P}^{m}$ is closed.

[image]

Of course, the definition of closed maps here

> **Def**. A map $f:X \to Y $ (between topological spaces) is called **closed** if $f(X) \subset Y $ is closed in $Y$ for any closed subset $A \subset X$.
> Next, I introduce the term of bihomogenous polynomial

> **Def**. A polynomial $f(x_0,...x_n,y_0,...y_n)$ is a **bihomogenous polynomial of bidegree** $d(=a+b)$ if it is homogenous w.r.t $x$ with
> degree $a$ and homogenous w.r.t $y$ with degree $b$. - For example, the polynomial $x_0x_1y_0^3 - 4 x_0^2 y_0y_1y_2$ is a bihomogenous polynomial with bidegree $5$.

Hence, the if the closed set $ Z \subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^m  $ is chosen, the result will be $\pi(Z)$ is closed , equivalently, elements of  $ \mathbb{P}^n \setminus \pi(Z)$ will not vanish for some homogenous polynomial. Within the proof,

- the form of $Z$ should be expressed as $Z=V(f_1,...,f_n)$ (where $f_i$'s are homogeneous polynomial)
- each polynomial $f_i(-,-) (i=1,2,...r) $ are bihomogenous of bidegree $d$

And next, the author fixed  $a \in \mathbb{P}^m$ define $g_i:=f_i(-,a) \in k[x_0,...x_n],  (i=1,...,r) $. we put $x (\in \mathbb{P}^{n})$ into given polynomial $g_i(x,a)$ Then,

> $x \in  \mathbb{P}^n \setminus \pi(Z)$  if and only if
> $k[x_0,....x_n]_{k} \subset (g_1,...,g_r)  $ for some $k \in
>  \mathbb{N}$ (where $k[x_0,....x_n]_{k}$ is a homogenous polynomial
> degree $k$-part of the polynomial ring) ..... (★)

Anyway, when considering the aim (to find the homogenous polynomial whose element in $\mathbb{P}^n \setminus \pi(Z) $ does not vanish), the above condition would be evidence about the desired polynomial. In fact, such polynomial consists of the following steps :

- consider the $k$-linear (surjective) map, $F_k : (k[x_0,...,x_n]_{k-d})^r \to k[x_1,...x_n]_{k} , (h_1,...h_r ) \mapsto h_1g_1+...+h_rg_r$
  with  $\operatorname{dim}_{k}k[x_0,...x_n]_{k}=\binom{n+k}{k}$ for some $k \ge d$ (I think that the upper script $r$ does not seem to mean the r-th'power', just choosing number of $r$ components)
  This is in turn if and only if at least one of the minors of size $\binom{n+k}{k}$ of matrix for some $F_k$ is nonzero. [!] But these minors are polynomials in the coefficients of $g$ and thus in the coordinates of $x$, and non-vanishing one of these minors is an open condition in $\mathbb{P}^n$

In my thought, since the $k$-linear map is surjective, the matrix $F_k$ is $\binom{n+k}{k} \times r $ matrix whose rank is $\binom{n+k}{k}$ and at least $\binom{n+k}{k} \le r$ to hold $\operatorname{rank} F_k = \binom{n+k}{k}$.This is the matrix that I can imagine..., So For example,

put $n=3$. If (★) holds a specific integer is $k=2$ . Then,
,
$F_2 : (k[x_0,...x_3]_{2-d})^{12} \to k[x_0,..,x_3]_{2}$ (here, put $r=12$) $(h_1,...h_{12} ) \mapsto h_1g_1+...+h_{12}g_{12} $. In that case, if $d=1$, the $h_1...,h_{12}$ are degree $1$, and $g_i(i=1,...,12) $ are also degree $1$. Then $\operatorname{dim}_{k}k[x_0,...x_3]_{2}=\binom{3+2}{2}=10$ This means the polynomial
$$(h_1,...h_{12}) \mapsto h_1g_1+...+h_{12}g_{12} = a_{00}x_{0}^2 + a_{01}x_{0}x_{1}+a_{02}x_{0}x_{2}+... a_{33}x_{3}^2$$

(i.e total coefficients one can think are $10$ cases , $a_{00},a_{01},a_{02},a_{03},a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},a_{22},a_{23},a_{33}$ )

Since $F_k$ is a $k$-linear map, $F_k$ is expressed by $10\times 12$ matrix,

$$\begin{bmatrix}
h_1\\\vdots  
\\ h_{12} \end{bmatrix} \mapsto  F_k \begin{bmatrix}
h_1\\\vdots  
\\ h_{12} \end{bmatrix}=  \begin{bmatrix}
y_{00}\\\vdots  
\\ y_{33}
\end{bmatrix}(=a_{00}x_{0}^2 + a_{01}x_{0}x_{1}+a_{02}x_{0}x_{2}+... a_{33}x_{3}^2)$$

**And I cannot understand [!] part within the proof**

- [!] But these minors are polynomials in the coefficients of $g$ and thus in the coordinates of $x$, and non-vanishing one of these minors is an open condition in $\mathbb{P}^n$.

To begin with, I can cosider $10 \times 10$ matrix and according to the definition of [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)), there exists  $(i,j)(1 \le i,j \le 10)$($i$-th column and $j$-th row) s.t $M_{i,j}=(-1)^{i+j}\operatorname{det} A_{i,j}$ (where $A_{i,j}$ is the matrix whose $i$-th column and $j$-th row vanish) is nonzero polynomial. But, I cannot understand why such minors are coefficient of polynomial $g$

Comment: such minors are polynomials in the coefficient of polynomial $g$ but not necessary coefficients of the polynomial $g$; so we only need the entries of the matrix $F_k$ be polynomials in the coefficient of polynomial $g$.